# how to add properties in a [from metadata] class

Tags: c#

i have a metadata class i cant edit in it but i want to add new properties in this class is there a work around or something which will let me add my properties ?

[This is the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef9IB.png)

Comment: You want to add properties to a compiled class - well you can't. Get access to that code, change it and recompile. Even if you could change it, how would the assembly where it came from have used it?

Comment: so, is there another way to add the properties ?

Comment: I just said you can't add properties.

Comment: i tried to use an automapper to map the class in another one and edit the new one
is there a work around like this ?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking now. If you have a new question, then post a new question. And please don't post images of code, that will quickly get your questions downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do is to use the concept of inheritance.
In such a way that you create a class and inherit it from your desired class. In the desired class, you can add a property or method or...

```
public class YouChildClass : UnitValue
{
    public string YourNewProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Now, instead of using class UnitValue, use class YouChildClass in the program

Comment: The class doesn't appear to be sealed, so this should work